# Java - Inheriting from a class that accepts generics?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

How do you inherit from this class? The following code is broken but it shows what I'm trying to achieve.

Bound Mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitude for the bounded parameter  of the type ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

```
public class MyClass<T> extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T> {
     public MyClass (Class<T> clazz) {
          super(clazz);
     }
}
```

Comment: Why do you say its broken? I think it will compile and look correct too.

Comment: I get the following compile error: Bound Mismatch

Comment: @aryaxt: Can you add your full error message to the question?

Comment: It doesn't like the second <T> in my code, and when I remove it instead of an error I get a warning because needs a generic

Comment: @aryaxt it complies fine for me in eclipse and here http://ideone.com/AbN5v . what version of jdk are you using?

Comment: I updated the cod with more details, I am basically trying to extend ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 to create a base class for my android tests

Comment: The only way you get that message is if you have bounds on `<T>` in the super class, eg `MySuper<T extends Something>`. I think you need to reboot your machine.

Comment: @aryaxt In your question you don't mention anything about `T extends SomeObject` and the code snippet you provided perfectly compiles for me. What else an i supposed to do?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed ??? It was rely useful for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the class definition of ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2?

Most likely, ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 is defined as:

```
class ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T extends SomeObject> {
 ...
}
```

In which case, your object's parameters needs to stay within its superclass's parameters.

For example:

```
public class MyObject<T extends SomeObject> extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T> {
...
}
```

You could also make the parameter narrower. So, if MySomeObject extended SomeObject you could also say:

```
public class MyObject<T extends MySomeObject> extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T> {
...
}
```

Edit to add:
I just found [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html). I assume you're using the same one, so it needs to be defined as:

```
public class MyObject<T extends android.app.Activity> extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T> {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem MyClass<T extends Activity> extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T>